# Terraform destroy with a json state file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, destroy

I created an infrastructure via Terraform with state file storing in S3.

Unfortunately due to some issues the local state file got corrupted and also it is not able to download the S3 file itself.

Is this possible to run `terraform destroy fileName` with the file stored on S3 (after I download it manually).

Comment: delete the local file, run `terraform init`, that should download the state from s3. In what way is anything corrupted right now? Does any state file actually reflect the AWS state? Do you want to destroy all created resources?

Comment: The local state file _.terraform/terraform.tfstate_ does not have anything regarding my infrastructure. It is showing backend set as S3 and all other values set to null for that. Also it has setup the infrastructure via workspace. Does it have to do anything with that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes download the `.tfstate` file and place the file in terraform root.

Now run `terraform init` and you are ready to go.

`terraform destroy resource.resource_name` will work.

Comment: what is the "terraform root"? I'm working in a monorepo with CDKTF. I tried a random "temp" folder, but I see `The directory has no Terraform configuration files`